# Driving IRF610 from 12v?

Tags: mosfet

I've got a few of [IRF610](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91023/91023.pdf) power MOSFETs.
I've got a 12 V circuit which draws 1.90 A when running at max.

I was thinking I could move the current circuits GND line to the drain of the IRF610, connect the Source to the GND of the power supply, then connect +12 V though a [4N25](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) to the Gate. (Then controlling the 4N25 from a separate 5 V circuit to control if the 12 V circuit is on or off.)

What I'm wondering about is using +12 V for the gate, when it needs +10 V, is this doable or should I find something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gate drive voltage is fine, but Drain-Source On resistance isn't. Typical R<sub>DSon</sub> is ~1.2 Ω at 25 °C junction temperature, going up to ~2.5 Ω at 150 °C. At 1.9A you can expect a voltage drop of ~1.2 Ω x 1.9 A = 2.3 V. That will generate 2.3 V x 1.9 A = 4.4 W of heat, which will quickly heat it up - increasing resistance and causing even higher voltage drop and temperature rise.

I recommend using a MOSFET with much lower R<sub>DSon</sub> and saving your IRF630's for high voltage applications. If you must use the IRF630 then wire several of them in parallel to reduce the total resistance and increase power handling.

Answer (score 1):

It needs 10V *to achieve the rated RDson*:
[image]
[image]

It does not that it can only operate on, or only withstand 10V. What can actually be applied to it is here:

[image]
[image]

In fact, you ideally drive such a MOSFET at 12-15V; Somewhere comfortably away from the absolute limit but well above the gate-source voltage for the rated RDson so you get at most that much resistance (especially when using a high-side bootstap where the applied gate-source decays the longer the MOSFET is on).

Answer (score 1):

Vgs < 20V is fine. see the datasheet.
[image]
Make sure Vgs turn fully on (> Vgs threshould) and fully off (about 0V)